# For loop for reverse words in an Edit

Tags: delphi, lazarus

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a:string;
    i:smallint;
begin
  a:=Edit1.text;
  for i:= 1 downto length(Edit1.Text) do
   begin
    Edit2.Text:= {last letter};
   end;
```

I'd like that the program takes the last letter of the word in `Edit1.Text` and puts it on `Edit2.Text`. What could I do? If you need here you can see a picture of the program:

[image]

Comment: Just for future reference: Your `for` loop makes no sense. You try to run it from `1 downto length(Edit1.Text)`, which means that unless `Edit1.Text` has a length of zero or a negative number (which of course is impossible) the loop will never run at all. It should be 'for i := Length(Edit1.Text) downto 1` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to use the function `ReverseString();` that is contained on StrUtils. So, first of all add `StrUtils` in your uses clause. Then put this code instead of that for loop:

```
begin
  a:=Edit1.text;
  Edit2.Text:=ReverseString(a);
end;
```

It is the same as yours, but this way is easier. Also, if you want the length of the string just write this code:

```
Edit3.Text:=IntToStr(length(your_edit.text));
```

Of course, instead of `your_edit`, type the correct name of the Edit.

Comment: Will this work if I have separate words too? like if I type "An Apple" it returns "elppA nA" right? :)

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli There is no word magic inside of string. It is just a bunch of chars and when reversed all chars of the string will be in reversed order as a simple and basic function

Answer (score 0):

> that the program takes the last letter of the word in `Edit1.Text`

So do you mean that there can be several words ? Then which word do you want or do you want to iterate all the words one by one ?

Or do you mean "last letter of the whole string" no matter if there is one word or many?

And do you really need all the letters reversed or only the last one ?

Actually, if you only need the single letter then the most efficient code would be

```
if SourceString > '' then
   DestString := SourceString[ Length( SourceString )]
else
   ... the source is empty... do something like showing error
```

Or using functions from `SysUtils` that have accounting for empty strings built in: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/rightstr.html

```
DestString := RightStr(SourceString, 1);
```

Reversing the whole string when you only need a single letter is an overkill, like bringing home a truck of apples to only eat one of those.

Comment: ^ or simply use ReverseString(); as DK64 suggested :)

Comment: @Emma - you did not answered the questions i asked in this answer. Maybe that is my English, maybe yours but your question is contradicting itself. Sure, you can cook an egg by setting hens shed on fire, but it is somewhat overkill, even if simple. So the question remain what do you actually want - letter or string, what is word for you and so on.